# Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css

I am new at html and css and when I increase my browser size my entire layout gets messed up and elements start overlapping one another. Can anyone show me a way to make my layout become responsive? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt you'll find anyone on Stackoverflow that's going to just make your whole website responsive. Maybe reading this will help you: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/

Comment: There is no quick, instantaneous, magical way of making your layout instantly responsive. Responsive/fluid design requires forethought and planning, and often designers opt to use a framework (such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)), that has already taken care of responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wanna do.

1) If you're learning HTML5 and CSS than you've got to watch towards bootstrap media queries to code fully responsive. To go further you will also need Javascript. There are also paying technologies.

2) If you just wanna make a responsive website without caring about the coding side, you should choose a CMS like Wordpress, Joomla etc... It will be faster for you and with a good responsive template, a very decent solution.

Answer (score -2):

There is a nice tutorial in w3schools that uses we3.css stylesheet framework, very easy to start and see the entire problem. It uses images of different size and adpat itself to pc, tablets, smarthpones. Try it, I mean read, it is a short one, and will help you a lot, can you implement without adding that file, but changing easily yours.

Comment: Please, not w3schools. If you want a proper framework, use one of the legitimate CSS boilerplates, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).